# JS number comparison for value grater than MAX_SAFE_INTEGER does not output correct result

Tags: javascript, numbers, max, angular9, bigint

I am having problem with getting the correct result for comparing number greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

I have tried bigInt but it does not work correctly.

```
i.e. bigInt(789255834696679425) > bigInt(789255834696679424)
still return false but the actual is true

console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
// expected output: 9007199254740991

function comparison(x) {
  if (789255834696679425 >789255834696679424) {
    return ('true');
  } else {
    return ('false');
 }
}

console.log(comparison()); // it return false
```

I have look at other attempt but could not find a solution. do you know if there is any alternative

update
so I tried 789255834696679425n > 789255834696679424n that return correct result
adding a n will convert it to BigInt. But BigInt will round up/down.

Comment: `789255834696679425n >789255834696679424n` works. `789255834696679425` just becomes `789255834696679400`, exact same for `789255834696679424`

Comment: big int should be a string.....

Comment: but bigInt will round up or down, will that return correct result for the comparison?

Comment: To clarify what epascarello is saying, try `BigInt('789255834696679425') < BigInt('789255834696679424')`

Comment: for the argument, convert it to string works thanks